# Flexbox that wraps around a fixed container

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create a form with a variable number of form fields that would expand horizontally. Each field would have a minimum width of 300 px, but would expand to fill the row if there is extra space. If there is not enough space for each field at 300px, then it would wrap to another row. Flexbox would be the perfect solution for this. However, I also want there to be a variable width container for submit & cancel buttons that is fixed on the right side of the first row. (See the attached illustration.)

[image: Flexbox wrapping around fixed container]

How can I create this fixed, right-aligned container that Flexbox would flow around? Can this be done with Flexbox alone? Would CSS Grid (or a combination of Flexbox & Grid) be helpful here? Example code would be appreciated.

Comment: without some *hack* there is no direct/trivial/generic way to do this with CSS grid or flexbox.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with an illustration of what I'm looking for. https://jsfiddle.net/lobo78/twy5a5pn/24/

Comment: I would like the child container with the buttons to not wrap, but stay on the first row, on the right side.

Comment: When wrapping what should happen?

Comment: As shown in the illustration in my question, every child element should be wrappable, except for the one child element with buttons which should remain fixed where it is on the right side of the first row.

Comment: updated codepen.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best solution is to use `float` and `inline-block`. then you can adjust sizing considering media query

```css
body>.container {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 24px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  border: solid 1px #F00;
  font-size:0;
}

.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 36px;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  min-width: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size:initial;
}

.box.buttons {
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.4" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="box buttons">
    <button>Submit</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box a">Box A</div>
  <div class="box b">Box B</div>
  <div class="box c">Box C</div>

  <div class="box e">Box E</div>
  <div class="box f">Box F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought Flexbox and Grid were so powerful that they were going to do away with all "float" layouts. I guess I was wrong...

Comment: @Daren well, float you remain usefull when you need to float (like in your case) and flexbox or grid are powerfull but cannot do this. It's wrong to think that one technique is better than another. Each one has its use cases, you simply need to choose the right one for each case.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I found that this **is** possible with CSS Grid. Here is the basic layout:

HTML:

```
<div class="auto-fit">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
  <div class="D">D</div>
  <div class="E">E</div>
  <div class="F">F</div>
  <div class="G">G</div>
  <div class="H">H</div>
  <div class="I">I</div>
  <div class="J">J</div>
  <div class="K">K</div>
  <div class="L">L</div>
  <div class="M">M</div>
  <div class="buttons"><button>Submit</button><button>Cancel</button></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.auto-fit {  
  display: grid;  
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;  
}

div.auto-fit > div {  
  background-color: #fff;  
  border-radius: 3px;  
  padding: 15px;  
  font-size: 14px;
}

div.buttons {
  grid-column: -1/-2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle that shows it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/lobo78/5ufqdm4y/22/